# MySQL Decimal Syntax Error when creating table

Tags: mysql

When I create a table using the decimal data types I keep getting syntax error and it keeps highlighting the decimal keyword

```
CREATE TABLE ADVENTURE_TRIP
(
TRIP_ID decimal(3,0) PRIMARY KEY,
TRIP_NAME varchar,
START_LOCATION char,
STATE char,
DISTANCE number,
MAX_GRP_SIZE number,
TYPE char,
SEASON char
);
```

Then When I try to instead use a double or float it will instead highlight the parentheses next to it arrow points to where sql highlights the error, float(3,0)

```
                                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fix two data types: varchar and number.
When you use varchar you need to specify the maximum length you can accept (for example varchar(10)). number I fear it can't work...I ran your code putting real, float or double instead of number and it works.